# Define vector space on irrational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is it possible to define a vector space on irrational numbers? I can define a group structure on irrational numbers but can i make it a vector space?

Comment: No! because the set of irrational numbers is not a field. It has no zero and no one.

Comment: Not with normal operation,perhaps we can define some operation with sth els as 0,1

Comment: Which group structure on the irrationals do you have in mind? $\qquad$

Comment: Of each cardinal we have a group,so not just irrationals foe every set it is possible to choose a bijection between tath set and a group of the same cardinal and return the operation to that set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Choose a bijection $\phi: I \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\phi$ lets you pull back the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure of $\mathbb{R}$ to $I$: define $0_I := \phi^{-1}(0)$, $i_1 +_I i_2 := \phi^{-1}(\phi(i_1) + \phi(i_2))$, $\alpha i := \phi^{-1}(\alpha \phi(i))$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $i_1,i_2,i \in I$. You may check that the vector space axioms are satisfied.

For example, the additive inverse of $i \in I$ is $\phi^{-1}(-\phi(i))$ because $$i + \phi^{-1}(-\phi(i)) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(i) + \phi(\phi^{-1}(-\phi(i)))) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(i) - \phi(i)) = \phi^{-1}(0) = 0_I.$$

Or to check compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication:
$$ \alpha(\beta i) = \alpha(\phi^{-1}(\beta \phi(i))) = \phi^{-1}(\alpha \phi(\phi^{-1}(\beta \phi(i))) ) = \phi^{-1}(\alpha \beta \phi(i) ) = (\alpha \beta)i.$$

Note that, perhaps interestingly, this also yields a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.